# Simplifying the vector expression $(5a+7b)×(-a+3b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

> Let $a$ and $b$ be three-dimensional vectors. Then
>   $(5a+7b)×(-a+3b)=ka×b$ for some scalar $k$. Find $k$.

Uhhhh I don't know how to start. Am I supposed to multiply the first 2 equations like $(5a^2+8ab+21b^2)$? maybe not tho...

Please provide tips to get started!! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said in your post about multiplying out the brackets - given that $a,b$ are vectors, you can't multiply them. It would seem that the $\times$ in your question is the symbol for the cross product. Are you familiar with cross products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you expand the expression first.
$$(5a+7b)×(-a+3b)=5a×-a+5a×3b+7b×-a+7b×3b$$
The cross product of any vector with a linear multiple of itself is zero:
$$=5a×3b+7b×-a$$
The cross product is also antisymmetric:
$$=5a×3b+a×7b=22a×b$$
Thus $k=22$.